# Serve empty 404 page with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, drupal, http-status-code-404

I have a `Drupal` website which contains the below default `mod_rewrite` rules

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That means that requests that match an existing file or directory will be served directly instead of triggering the `index.php` script.

The problem is that requests to non-existing files do not match the above rules and get redirected to `index.php` which bootstrap the entire `Drupal` application and unnecessarily load the website.

In order to bypass `Drupal` for missing files I have created the following rules:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.jpg|.jpeg|.css|.js|.png)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

This works, but the problem is that the `404` redirects relies on `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` which ends up bootstrapping `Drupal`.

I need to keep `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` because `Drupal` is used to serve useful `404` pages for dynamic content. I tried to define several `ErrorDocument 404` (1 before my rules and 1 before the Drupal rules) but only the last one applies.

**Q: How can I serve an empty `404` page for requests to non-existing files without changing the `ErrorDocument 404` directive?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want: [Emulating ErrorDocuments with Mod_Rewrite](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial/#Emulating_ErrorDocuments_Mod_Rewrite)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the relevant parts of the solution in your answer than relying on links to an offsite resource.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different HTTP status code instead?

Say, 403 (Forbidden) - what does it matter what the (malicious) client sees?

Comment: because I use `Google webmaster tools` to monitor broken pages on my website and I would like missing files to be flagged as `404` and not `403`.